# error in untarring

Tags: tar, texlive

I am now trying to install Texlive 
 ON UBUNTU 2015, but I get this installation  S error :

```
untar: untarring /usr/local/texlive/2015/temp/amsfonts.tar failed (in /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist)
untarring /usr/local/texlive/2015/temp/amsfonts.tar failed, stopping install.
Installation failed.
```

and then 
I check the tar version on my system but that was :
 tar is already the newest version.
what is the solution
pleas help me as soon as possible
thanks.

Comment: *How* exactly are you trying to install it? please [edit] your question to include the steps you followed

Comment: I think probably  My problem refer to the connection  source that i choose for downloading Texllive .... i m not sure . i get the installer in this form : .gz from the:  http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html . and then run : sudo perl install-tl

Comment: What s the best source for get update ubuntu & for example texlive from Iran , did u know?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest re-downloading that .tar. If it was corrupted, then it could cause that error, I think :).